# Using clj-http client to automate login

Tags: clojure

I've just seen this library https://github.com/technomancy/clojure-http-client with this snippet of code on the README page which is what I'm looking to do

```
(res/with-cookies {}
  (res/post "http://localhost:3000/login" {} {"user" user "password" password})
  (res/get "http://localhost:3000/my-secret-page))
```

However it appears that the lib is deprecated and it advises you to use the `clj-http` library instead. I'm just wondering if anyone knows how to replicate this sort of behaviour using that library?

At the moment I just do

```
(post "<site i want to login to>" {:form-params {:username "<my username>" :password "<my password>"}})
```

Which returns a cookie that has a http 302 redirect to the authenticated page, but I have no idea how to make the client follow this redirect using the authenticated cookie

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FYI I resolved this,

```
(defn login [login-url user pass]
  (let [result (client/post "http://my-site.com/login" {:form-params {:username user :password pass}})]
    (when (= (:status result) 302)
      (:cookies result))))
```

Should login be successful it will return a cookie map, this can then be used in subsequent requests when visiting pages that require you to be logged in, e.g.

```
(when-let [cookies (login "http://my-site.com" "my-user" "my-pass")]
  (client/get "http://my-site.com/user-page" { :cookies cookies }))
 => <html><head><title>Hello my-user!</titl.......
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to explicitly use `follow-redirect` function from the library.